# WPF Model-View-ViewModel Toolkit

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i downloaded this toolkit http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962 installed but cannot find WPF model-view application in my visual studio 2010. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by user janeggert in the reviews of this download:

In order to get the template running in VS2010, edit the file WpfModelViewApplicationProjectTemplate.cs.vstemplate in the template zip file: Simply remove the line Microsoft.VisualStudio.Presentation.Extensions, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 Copy the modified zip file to the project templates folder. Seems to work like a charm..